# Is there a plugin to improve Confluence's search?

Tags: confluence

Our team uses confluence as our enterprise wide knowledge sharing system. It's fine, but the search for Confluence is god awful. I've talked to people at other firms and they've had similar complaints.

The specific question...Is there a plugin for Confluence to change the search algorithm that it's using?

Comment: We have often the same problem in our Confluence projects. We've discussed a Solr plugin for Confluence and JIRA. It should be easy if the original index remains and you create an alternative index for searching. But unfortunately we're having not time to do this now.

Comment: I encourage you to go and vote for this: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFCLOUD-14910

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try the Confluence Awesome Search Plugin : https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/32021

Comment: Sadly, that plugin isn't supported on the new versions of Confluence. I did however find the following article which makes Confluence search somewhat better, but not great. https://www.adaptavist.com/display/ADAPTAVIST/2011/12/07/5+Best+Practice+Tips+to+Improve+Search+in+Atlassian's+Confluence+Wiki

Answer (score 0):

I might take a look at this:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ZFIN.instantsearch

However, that will not change the underlying search algorithm for populating their search.  Its possible that it is significantly better in 5.x as I know they have made significant improvements.